# How to ouput a date punctually in another language in R

Tags: r, date, output

I usually set my working environment in English although it is not my mother tongue, because most dates I use in input are this way.

However, I sometimes to *output* a date in a long format in another language, usually French.

```
library(lubridate) 
today()
> today()
[1] "2020-12-22"
```

That is, I would like a function that gives :

```
DateInLongFormatInFrench(today)
[1] "Mardi 22 décembre"
```

Which is the French for "Tuesday, December the 22th". And I would like the solution not to change the language setting for the whole program, but just this instance.

I have found a lot of post on how to read dates, but not so much on how to output them

Comment: It would depend on your locale settings.  Otherwise, `format(today(), '%A %d %B')` should work

Comment: The `withr` package is useful for changing the locale settings for a single line. (Though I'm having trouble on Windows with French---you may have an easier time if you're not on windows.) But if you can find the right locale settings / your OS is more compliant than mine, something like `withr::with_locale("LC_TIME" = "fr_FR", format(today(), '%A %d %B'))` should work.

Answer (score 5):

Convert dates to strings using `format.Date`

```
format(<my_date>, "%A %d %B")
```

You must have your locale set to a Francophone region, e.g.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "fr_FR")
```

If you need to do this in isolation:

```
frenchDate <- function(x) {
  locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
  
  # when function exits, restore original locale
  on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale))

  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "fr_FR")

  format(x, "%A %d %B")
}
```

Comment: note for future readers that the locale also has to be available: I get "OS reports request to set locale to 'fr_FR' cannot be honored", presumably because it's not installed

Comment: I think this is the right way to go. It can be generalized a little if desired, with `function(x, format = "%A %d %B", locale = "fr_FR") { ...; format(x, format = format); }`, thereby allowing non-hard-coded formats and locales. (That suggests a name like `format_locale` or similar.)

Comment: Yeah, locale names are OS-dependent. `?locales` has a pretty good rundown.